# Rails test failing due to ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I think I might be suffering from tunnel vision because I can't see what other argument is needed on line 22, following my comment.

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class RecipesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      setup do
        @recipe = recipes(:one)
        login_as(:one)
      end

      test "should get index" do
        get :index
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil assigns(:recipes)
      end

      test "should get new" do
        get :new
        assert_response :success
      end

      test "should create recipe" do

        # it's complaining about this test
        test "should show recipe" do
          get :show, id: @recipe, user_id: @recipe.user_id
          assert_response :success
        end

        test "should get edit" do
          get :edit, id: @recipe
          assert_response :success
        end

        test "should update recipe" do
          patch :update, id: @recipe, recipe: { image_url: @recipe.image_url, instructions: @recipe.instructions, title: @recipe.title, user_id: @recipe.user_id }
          assert_redirected_to recipe_path(assigns(:recipe))
        end

        test "should destroy recipe" do
          assert_difference('Recipe.count', -1) do
            delete :destroy, id: @recipe, user_id: @recipe.user_id
          end

          assert_redirected_to recipes_path
        end
      end
    end
```

I think the show method only needs the id to locate the recipe. I've tried including

```
user_id: @recipe.user_id
```

but I still get the same only 1 argument for 2 error message.

*Please note: This is one of my first Rails projects, aka, I'm an extreme noob here. I welcome all constructive criticism about anything you see. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a test block inside a test block?

```
test "should create recipe" do

  # it's complaining about this test
  test "should show recipe" do
```

Remove the outer `test "should create recipe" do` and add it at the same level as `test "should show recipe" do`

Comment: I don't know, but I'll remove it and see. These were mainly rails generated tests. I'm definitely curious as to why and will look into it. Thanks!